Запуск инвалидации google cdn cache для одного load balancer запускает инвалидацию и для другого load balancer
У меня есть 2 окружения: prod и staging. Для каждого окружения созданы cloud storage buckets, где хранятся статические файлы сайта. Также созданы отдельные для каждого окружения load balancers с backend buckets, субдомены (sub.example.com and sub-staging.example.com) с разными static ip.
Когда я нажимаю кнопку "Invalidate" на вкладке "Caching" на странице "Load balancer details", кэш инвалидируется для staging и prod load balancers. Но когда я нажимаю кнопку "Invalidate" для prod load balancer, то кэш инвалидируется только для prod load balancer.

То же самое происходит, когда я выполняю команду "gcloud compute url-maps invalidate-cdn-cache my-lb-staging --path "/*" --async".
Также я создал третье окружение test, и аналогично все ресурсы cloud cdn. В итоге запуск инвалидации для test запускает инвалидацию для prod, но не для staging.
Я новичок в devops и google cloud, пожалуйста, помогите мне понять, в каком направлении двигаться, чтобы выяснить, в чем проблема.
